# How do you fetch an svg file and use it as <svg>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, svg, inline-svg

## My Question:

How do I fetch a ***.svg*** file and use it with `<svg>` tag, so I could also interactively style it (on hover for example), ***and not like I did in my example*** with `<img>` tag?

### Goal:

Create a thumbnail view that shows the flag of each country (149 in number) on my main route `'/'`

### Problem:

I've set a static route in my Express code, so all the flags to be available.

***server.js:***

```
app.use('/flags', express.static(FLAGS_FILES));
app.get('/flags', async (req, res) => {
    let myFlags;

    await readdir('data/flag-icons/')
        .then((flags) => myFlags = flags)
        .catch(err => console.log('Error:', err))

    res.json(myFlags)
});
```

On the client-side, I want to fetch each .svg file and inline it into my Component.

My React Component look like this:

***MapThumbnail Component:***

```
render(){
        const {flagcode} = this.props;
        const filepath = `/flags/${mapcode}/vector.svg`;

        console.log('filepath:', filepath);
        return (
            <MapThumbnailStyle>
                <img src={filepath} 
                     alt={flagcode} 
                     title={flagcode} 
                     width='40px' 
                     height='40px' 
                />
            </MapThumbnailStyle>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **in most of** the cases directly inline the contents of the SVG file inside the `render` function, like -

### TL;DR

[react-svg-loader](https://github.com/boopathi/react-svg-loader)

It provides a webpack-loader, a CLI, and a few other tools that convert an SVG file to a React Component which contains the SVG file's contents inline in the render method.

The gist of the idea is the following -

#### vector.svg

```
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" stroke-width="5" />
</svg>
```

#### Vector.js

Now create a `vector.js` and just copy the contents of the SVG like below

```
import React from "react"
export default () => (
  <svg>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" stroke-width="5" />
  </svg>
);
```

and you can hand edit some elements here or assign ids to animate them.

#### MapThumbnail Component

And in your MapThumbnail component, you can import it as JS and style the SVG the way you want -

```
import Vector from "./path/to/vector";

// ...
// ...

render() {
  return <div>
    <Vector />
  </div>
}
```

This conversion of SVG to a React Component can be automated to some levels and is provided by a few tools - one such tool is [react-svg-loader](https://github.com/boopathi/react-svg-loader). Disclaimer - I'm the author of react-svg-loader.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-inlinesvg looks like it would help you.

Comment: The package **react-svg** also worked very nice for me.
but I still try to understand how to do it 'natively'

https://github.com/atomic-app/react-svg

Comment: @ueeieiie check the source of those libraries to see how they do it?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is Lazy load the SVG component

```
const SvgComponent = React.lazy(() => import('../filepath.svg'))

return (
  <React.Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</P>}>
    <SvgComponent />
  </React.Suspense>
)
```

And this solution also works in React Native along with [react-native-svg-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-transformer) module.